# Where to upload javascript file online and how to source it properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find how where and how to upload my scripts where I can source them as an external script.

I can't seem to find any question like this or maybe I'm not good enough in searching

But anyway, my situation is, I need to upload script online, a basic `document.write` to save space.

It cannot be a file on the same folder of storage as my pages because it's for work, and pages should be shareable to people as a standalone file so they don't have to extract it anymore.

Now I have tried to upload it online on different types of cloud or host, but I can't source it, because of security purposes I think?

Or maybe the source tag I should use must be different if it's online?
is it not `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://abc.blabla.com/files/includes/html/page-links.js"></script>`

Please please help. The main goal I have here is to upload my scripts online, and be able to source it as an external script on my "static and local website"

Thank you,
Renz

Comment: Questions asking for off-site recommendations are off-topic here because they tend to attract spam. That includes web hosting recommendations.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the wrong choice of words, however, what I would like to know instead is, if it's possible to source an external script from a "dummy" website that hosts my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are getting into to issues in most browsers when trying to load javascript from one domain (your-website.com) to another (localhost).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You can try loading your browser with CORS disabled (Chrome):
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Or with a plugin such as these:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/cors

Comment: There are no Same Origin Policy restrictions on loading scripts.

Comment: I guessed the key part of the question was actually in the last sentence.

Answer (score -1):

You can do static hosting in firebase. once you host the files there then you can use the file link in script tag.

```
<script src="https://test.firebaseapp.com/file.js" ></script>
```